# Function calls seen before _start and main in backtrace

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, backtrace

I received a backtrace of my program (qt app running on RHEL 5.3) from a coworker and as I was analyzing it I found something I could not explain.  If you look at this backtrace, you will notice the trace for main and _start.  But before that we see _ZN19datalog_render_area9prepStripEh  and _ZN12QMutexLockerD1Ev which are in my program.  How can I see some of my functions getting called before the _start and main.  Isn't that impossible? (pardon the layout of my backtrace)

```
Funct Addr| Instr. Addr | FunctionSymbol  
----------|-------------|----------------------------------------------------------|  
0x8060bf2 | 0x8060dc0   | _Z11print_tracev  
0x8061386 | 0x806141c   | _Z15myMessageOutput9QtMsgTypePKc  
0x822b558 | 0x822b598   | _ZN5QListIP13QStandardItemEixEi  
0x8229ece | 0x8229f0b   | _ZN12vehicleModel14updHeaderModelEP5QListIjE  
0x822be7e | 0x822bf64   | _ZN14vehTableWidget19updVehicleTabLayoutEib  
0x822c668 | 0x822c8e7   | _ZN14vehTableWidget13setupVehTableEib  
0x82845f8 | 0x82846fc   | _ZN14vehTableWidget11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv
```

...function calls outside the program

```
0x8060e86 | 0x80612ce | main  

_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 4804252  

0x8060a70 | 0x8060a91 | _start  

_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 3218418744  

0x808df02 | 0x808df13 | _ZN12QMutexLockerD1Ev    

_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 3218420336  
_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 152429104  
_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 3218420552  

0x8208fa6 | 0x820acd0 | _ZN19datalog_render_area9prepStripEh  

_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 3218420336  
_____________________|____________________|address outside of program: 3218420500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you're seeing garbage on the stack. In order to get an accurate stack trace, the debugger needs either frame pointers (often omitted on x86 to save a register) or debug information. Without this information, it tries to guess - it scans through the stack for pointers that look sorta-kinda-like code addresses, and does its best to match them to the functions they belong to.

As others have mentioned, static initialization can cause code to be executed before `main`, but this code has returned by the point `main` is run, so they have no business being on the true stack trace. I would say that, most likely, everything beyond _start is garbage data and can be safely ignored.

Comment: that's a good thought.  I am calling the backtrace function with a depth of 300 so I am probably like you say, looking at garbage.  Now that I think of it, im sure the stack was very short in the qt creator debugger window when I recreated it there.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. For instance these functions could be called as part of the dynamic initialization of some static storage duration object.

Toy example:

```
const bool i = []() -> bool
{
    // arbitrary code here
    return true;
}();

int
main()
{}
```

Comment: It's true that static initializers may exist, but since they return before main, it shouldn't appear on an accurate stack trace of main.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a class that has a static data member. The constructor for that static data member is calling QMutexLocker. Static data members are constructed before main() is called.

Comment: I'll work on modifying _ZN19datalog_render_area9prepStripEh  until it doesn't have to be static anymore.  There is an access to a data member from another object which is another thread and this specific variable can very well be written/read simultaneously by this other thread.  That should lead to something

Comment: i also went through the whole code and found 2 static members I got rid of. thx

Comment: _ZN12QMutexLockerD1Ev is a destructor, not a constructor.

Comment: @yan, also, static members aren't the same thing as static constructors. Static constructors are when you have a static _data_ member, or a static _global (or file-scope) variable_, which has a type with a constructor.

Comment: @bdonlan, where can I find the meaning of those characters wrapping the symbol name, in this case ZN12 and D1Ev

Comment: @yan, use the `c++filt` utility

Comment: Or just do the demangling by hand: http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#demangler . `_ZN`=this is a nested mangled name. `12QMutexLocker`: The class. `D1`: The complete object destructor. `E`: End of function name. `v`: void arguments. In other words, `_ZN12QMutexLockerD1Ev` means `~QMutexLocker()`. Similarly, `_ZN19datalog_render_area9prepStripEh` is `datalog_render_area::prepStrip(unsigned char)`.